# Parse JSON with colon in key

Tags: python, django, json, django-templates

I am trying to parse the following JSON using Python / Django:

```
[
  {
    "street": "KEELER",
    ":id": 1421
  }
]
```

Within my Django templates, I can successfully access the street key like:

```
{{ obj.street }}
```

but cannot access the id. I have tried the following (all taken from various SO questions):

```
{{ obj.id }} , {{ obj.:id }}, {{ obj[':id'] }}
```

I have seen the couple of other questions in SO addressing a similar issue, but none seem to help.

Comment: Try to fix the json data rather than trying to figuring out how to work with bad json data.

Comment: this is json data coming from a government site using Socrata Open Data api (soda). I have no access to it. This is how the data is presented.

Comment: Is the close quote on :id intentionally missing?

Comment: What json parser (what does your import and parse code look like) and python version are you using?

Comment: I think You can iterate over `iteritems` and select value by key which satisfy your requirements.

Comment: As well as what @Pace has mentioned, is the trailing `,` also deliberate?

Comment: @Progger ahhh okies - so simply, you just want to know how to access that in a Django template - the JSON data is actually well formed...

Comment: @Progger have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252387/how-do-i-access-dictionary-keys-that-contain-hyphens-from-within-a-django-templa

Comment: @Progger Even if the data comes from a third-party, you must be passing it in via a `Context` at some point, so you ought to be able to translate `:id` to `id` at that point.

Comment: @JonClements has the crux of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @Aya recommended, what I did was dump the JSON to a string, replace all instances of ":id" with "id", then convert it back to JSON. At that point, I was able to access the ID like:

```
{{ obj.id }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object is wrapped in an array.

```
obj = [
  {
    "street": "KEELER",
    ":id": 1421
  }
]
```

`:id` should be accessed like `obj[0][':id']`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. :( Django has some deep magic that I don't like very much. (I'm subscribed to the python list but not the django list)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own parser and just parse the json as a string, there you can add custom parsing features to the id field. Although being in java, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462076/how-do-you-parse-json-with-a-colon-in-the-name-android-java) might help

Comment: if you click the link, they implement the corresponding functionality in java